# Rustに於いての「.iter()」メソッド等イテレータの存在意義とは

Tags: rust

```
// Code 1
fn main(){
    for vect in vec![0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].iter(){
        println!("{}",vect);
    }
}
```

例えば上記のコードを実行すると、縦に整列した10個の数字を得ることができます。同時に、

```
// Code 2
fn main(){
    for vect in vec![0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]{
        println!("{}",vect);
    }
}
```

でも同じ結果を得ることができます。ここで本題ですが、`Code 1`と`Code 2`では何が異なるのでしょうか？
またRustにおけるイテレータの存在意義とは？

自分の古巣のRubyにもイテレーターはありましたが、全て`for`で解決していたため、結局何のために（目標のデータを反復することには間違いない）用意されているのか疑問に思っていました。参考文献を読んでも`イテレーターの存在意義を前もって知っている事`を前提に書かれおり非常に悩んでいます。

Answer (score 18, accepted):

こんにちは。ちょっと長くなりますが、お付き合い下さい。

## Code 1とCode 2の違い

まずは本題にお答えすると、Code 1とCode2では所有権の扱いが異なります。後程説明しますが、Code 1もCode 2も（内部的に）イテレータを使ったコードになっているので、イテレータを使うかどうかという違いはないです。

Code 1では `vec!` で作られた値を参照しており、 Code 2では `vec!` で作られた値を消費しています。これは1. `vect` の型が `&i32` か `i32` か、 2. `for` 式文のあとでベクトルが使えるかどうか、で違いが表われます。少しコードを書き換えて試してみましょう。

```rust
// Code 1
fn main(){
    // 一旦変数を束縛しておく
    let vec = vec![0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
    for vect in vec.iter() {
        // vecを参照しているので、要素も参照になる
        // vectは&i32
        let vect: &i32 = vect;
        println!("{}",vect);
    }
    // forのあともvecを使える
    println!("{:?}", vec);
}
```

```rust
// Code 2
fn main(){
    // 一旦変数を束縛しておく
    let vec = vec![0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
    for vect in vec {
        // vecを消費しているので、要素をそのまま取り出せる
        // vectはi32
        let vect: i32 = vect;
        println!("{}",vect);
    }
    // forのあとvecを使おうとすると所有権エラー
    // println!("{:?}", vec);

    // error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `vec`
    //  --> iter.rs:8:22
    //   |
    // 2 |     let vec = vec![0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
    //   |         --- move occurs because `vec` has type `std::vec::Vec<i32>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
    // 3 |     for vect in vec {
    //   |                 ---
    //   |                 |
    //   |                 value moved here
    //   |                 help: consider borrowing to avoid moving into the for loop: `&vec`
    // ...
    // 8 |     println!("{:?}", vec);
    //   |                      ^^^ value borrowed here after move
    // 
    // error: aborting due to previous error
    // 
    // For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0382`
}
```

## イテレータの存在意義

### イテレータと `for` の関係

次にイテレータの存在意義ですが、一番分かりやすいのは `for` 式文のためです。`for` とイテレータは独立したものではなく、 `for` はイテレータを便利に使うための構文なのです。

Rustで `for` を書いたときは、コンパイラが裏で `while let` という構文とイテレータを使った表現に書き換えています。

```rust
// for
for e in v {
    // do something
}
```

```rust
// 上の式はこう展開される
let mut iter = v.into_iter();
while let Some(e) = iter.next() {
    // do something
}
```

Rubyも同様に `for` 文は `each` で書き換えられます（参考: [制御構造 (Ruby 2.7.0 リファレンスマニュアル)](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/doc/spec=2fcontrol.html#for)）

RubyでもRustでも配列や範囲(`start..end`)など、違うオブジェクトを `for` で扱えるのはイテレータで抽象化しているからなのです。

### その他の存在意義

イテレータの他の存在意義は

1. 「くりかえせるもの」という概念を抽象化する
2. `for` でやりがちな処理をメソッドとして共通化できる
3. （Rustにおいては）パフォーマンス上のメリットもある

などが挙げられます。3は少し込み入るので1, 2についてだけ触れます。

#### 1.「くりかえせるもの」という概念を抽象化するについて

Rubyだとダックタイピングがあるので意義が薄いですが、Rustだと概念の抽象化は必須です。例えばベクトルを拡張する [`extend` メソッド](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-Extend%3CT%3E)はこういう型シグネチャをしています。

```rust
fn extend<I>(&mut self, iter: I) where
    I: IntoIterator<Item = T>,
```

イテレート可能なもの（正確には `IntoIterator` を実装している型ですが）ならなんでも引数にとれます。このおかげで、次のようにベクトルやスライス、範囲などさまざまなものを引数にとれます。

```rust
let mut vec = vec![1];
// Vec<T> を渡せる
vec.extend(vec![2, 3]);
// &[T] を渡せる
vec.extend([4, 5, 6]);
// Range<T> を渡せる
vec.extend(7..10);
```

このように、「くりかえせるもの」を値として扱いたいときに有用です。

#### 2.`for` でやりがちな処理をメソッドとして共通化できるについて

そのままですが、よくある処理をメソッドとして共通化できると便利です。例えば「最初の5要素の和をとる」処理はイテレータを使えばRustでこう書けます。

```rust
vec.into_iter().take(5).sum()
```

同じことは `for` でも書けますが、 5つ数えたり合計値を収める変数を用意したり、ちょっと手間がかかりますよね？それらをメソッドにまとめることで手間を節約できます。あるいは、 [`zip`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.zip)のように `for` では少し書きづらいような処理もメソッドにできます。

## まとめ

以上で `vec![]` と `vec![].iter()` の違いと、イテレータの存在意義が伝わったでしょうか。蛇足になりますが、下に余談が2つ続きます。

## 余談

### 余談1 `for vect in vec![..].iter() { /* ... */}` について

先程説明したとおり、この式は以下のように展開されます。

```rust
let mut vec = vec![..].iter().into_iter();
while let Some(vect) = vec.next() {
    // ...
}
```

`vec![..].iter().into_iter()` という式が出てきましたね。イテレータを2回とっているようで無駄に見えるのは置いておきましょう。
注目するのは返り値です。この式は `std::slice::Iter` を返します。ところで、 `Vec` から `std::slice::Iter` を得るのは実は別のやり方があります。`(&vec![..]).into_iter()` でも同じものが出てくるのです。
つまり、 `vec![..].iter()` == `vec![..].iter().into_iter()` == `(&vec![..]).into_iter()` です。`into_iter` は `for` が勝手につけてくれるので、結局以下の2つの式は同等ということになります。

```rust
// .iter() を呼ぶやりかた
for vect in vec![..].iter() {
    // ...
}
```

```rust
// &をつけるやりかた
for vect in &vec![..] {
    // ...
}
```

Rustではイテレータを意識しない `&vec![..]` の方が好ましい書き方とされています。See [explicit_iter_loop](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/stable/index.html#explicit_iter_loop)

### 余談2 内部イテレータと外部イテレータ

RubyのイテレータとRustのイテレータは実は種類が違います。Rubyのものは内部イテレータ、Rustのものは外部イテレータと呼ばれます。

Rubyのものは `it.each {|e| ... }` のように、処理をメソッドに渡してしまうスタイルです。これはイテレータ自身が繰り返し処理を担当します。

Rustのものは `while let Some(e) = it.next() { ... }` のように、他の制御構造と組合せて使うスタイルです。

今回の質問にこれらの違いが関係することはないのですが、両者をないまぜにしてイテレータのことを考えていると混乱しかねないので一言補足しました。

Comment: 詳しい説明ありがとうございます。おかげさまで疑問が解決しました。今後もお世話になるとおもいますが、その時はよろしくお願いします。